# When does downward closure commute with supremum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be a suplattices, and suppose we have a family $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq A.$

> Is $\bigcup_{i\in I}(\operatorname{\downarrow}a_i) = \operatorname{\downarrow} \sup_{i\in I}(a_i)$ in general?

Here $\downarrow a$ means the principal downward closed sets (order ideal) generated by $a.$

I believe this assertion is wrong in general, and my counter example is $I=\{1, 2\}$ and $A=\{0\lt a_1\lt 1, 0\lt a_2\lt a\lt 1\}.$ Then $\operatorname{\downarrow} a_1\cup\operatorname{\downarrow} a_2=\{0, a_1, a_2\}$ while $\operatorname{\downarrow}(a_1\lor a_2)=A.$
Am I correct?

> Are there any obvious conditions on $A$ or $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ that would guaranteed the property in the above question?

I am looking for a condition like $A$ being distributive. This sounds like a very vague question. But, hopefully more experienced people can tell me something useful.

Comment: By suplattice, do you mean [join-semilattice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice)?

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what you are asking for, but I think you want every element $x\in A$ to be join prime: $x\leq a\lor b$ entails $x\leq a$ or $x\leq b$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sup_{i\in I}(\operatorname{\downarrow}a_i)$?  In what poset are you computing this sup?

Comment: Also, suplattice usually does not mean the same thing as join-semilattice.  Instead, it means *complete* join-semilattice.

Comment: @EricWofsey:  In the powerset of $A$ ordered by inclusions. Ohhh... thank you for the clarification. I meant "complete join-semilattices".

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: Sorry for the confusion. Here $A$ admits arbitrary joins, therefore a complete join-semilattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is virtually never true.  Since $\sup_{i\in I}(a_i)\in \operatorname{\downarrow} \sup_{i\in I}(a_i)$, the only way your equality can hold is if $\sup_{i\in I}(a_i)\in \operatorname{\downarrow}a_i$ for some $i$.  That is, you must have $\sup_{i\in I}(a_i)\leq a_i$ for some $i$, which means that $a_i$ is greater than equal to every $a_j$, so your family $(a_i)$ must have a greatest element.  (And of course, if the family does have a greatest element $a_i$, then your equality does hold since both sides are just equal to $\operatorname{\downarrow}a_i$.)

Comment: Thank you for this very clear answer. The motivation for this question was, I have a suplattice homomorphism $f: A\to B$ and a family $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq A$ for which the induced map $\bigcup_{i\in I}(\operatorname{\downarrow}a_i)\xrightarrow{}\bigcup_{i\in I}(\operatorname{\downarrow}f(a_i))$  is an order isomorphism. I would like to lift this to an isomorphism between $\operatorname{\downarrow} \sup_{i\in I}(a_i)$ and $\operatorname{\downarrow} \sup_{i\in I}(f(a_i)).$ Do you think this is still possible?

Comment: No, that is not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by Eric Wofsey below points out, this condition always fails for $I=\varnothing$. We can however give a characterisation of the algebras where the statement you wrote is true for all nonempty indices $I$. This is the case if and only if $A$ is a linear order with no infinite ascending chain.

First, notice that your condition is equivalent to claim that every nonzero element in $A$ is *completely join prime*: $x\leq \bigvee_{i\in I} a_i$ entails $x\leq a_i$ for some $i\in I.$ We can show that every element of $A$ is completely join prime if and only if $A$ is a linear order with no infinite ascending chain.

If $A$ is linear and has no infinite ascending chain, then $x\leq\bigvee_{i\in I} a_i=a_j$ for some $j\in I$, hence $x$ is join prime.

Conversely, (i) if $A$ is not linear, then there is some $x=y\lor z$ with $y,z$ incomparable. Hence $x\leq y \lor z$ but $x\nleq y$ and $x\nleq z$, meaning that $x$ is not join prime. (ii) If $A$ is linear but has an ascending chain  $\{a_i\}_{i<\omega}$, we obtain $\bigvee_{i<\omega}\{a_i\}\leq \bigvee_{i<\omega}\{a_i\}$ but $\bigvee_{i<\omega}\{a_i\}\nleq a_n$ for all $n\in\omega$, hence $\bigvee_{i<\omega}\{a_i\}$ is not join prime.

Comment: This is not quite right: every $A$ will fail the statement when $I$ is empty.  (In other words, the least element of a suplattice is never completely join prime.)

Comment: You are right, thanks for the remark, I polished the answer in light of your comment -- hope it's fine to edit it.